# Post a model property with DisplayFor on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel, displayfor

My one view page I passed in a model through the controller, so I can write:
`@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)` which displays the First Name of the model. When I try to submit the form on the page using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { UserViewModel = Model }))
```

and I take a look at my model in

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel model)
{
    //model.FirstName is blank
```

Is there anyway I can make the model.FirstName not blank? by some how passing the model that I originally passed? I could set a bunch of hidden remarks, though if there is a better way that would be very helpful

EDIT: the DisplayFor is just an example to show the model is accessible. I actually have about 15 fields, and I am going through multiple forms trying to populate the model.  Is Hidden the only way? and could I just hide the entire model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor()` creates a simple literal with the value by default (if you're not using a display template), on submit only form elements being submitted to the server.

You can use hidden input.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Which will be something like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{the first name}" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
```

Comment: oh, that was just an example, showing that the model is accessible. I actually have about 15 fields, and I am going through multiple forms trying to populate the model.  Is Hidden the only way? and could I just hide the entire model?

Comment: @FreshJays, Yes I'm sorry you will have to use hidden inputs for all of your model properties. By the way, what I do is just save the model primary key as a hidden input and query for that model in the server from the database. Not sure this is your case though...

Comment: yep that will work, I was trying not to get the database involved until the end, but that will definitely work